# Android SQLite ContentValues not inserting

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to insert values into `SQLite` Database for Android Application.
I am writing following code:

```
public class DataBaseAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "AlarmSystem";

// Alarm table name
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Alarms";

//AlarmTable Columns names
private static final String KEY_ALARM_ID = "Id";
private static final String KEY_DESC = "Description";
private static final String KEY_REPEAT_DAY = "RepeatDay";
private static final String KEY_REPEAT_TYPE = "REPEAT_TYPE";
private static final String KEY_CALENDAR = "Calendar";
private static final String KEY_APP = "Device";
private static final String KEY_ACTIVE = "Active";

//creating database
public DataBaseAdapter(Context con)
{
    super(con, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

//creating table
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    String CREATE_TABLE = "Create Table "+TABLE_NAME+"("
            +KEY_ALARM_ID+" integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT, "+KEY_DESC+" TEXT, "+KEY_REPEAT_DAY+ " TEXT,"
            +KEY_REPEAT_TYPE+" integer, "+KEY_CALENDAR+" TEXT, "+KEY_APP+" TEXT, "+KEY_ACTIVE+" integer );";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}
//updating database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}
public void addAlarm(Alarm alarm)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_DESC, alarm.getDesc());
    values.put(KEY_REPEAT_DAY, alarm.getRepeatDay());
    values.put(KEY_REPEAT_TYPE, alarm.getRepeatType());
    values.put(KEY_CALENDAR, Long.toString(alarm.getCalendarInMillis()));
    values.put(KEY_APP, alarm.getApp());
    values.put(KEY_ACTIVE, alarm.getActive());

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

I don't know what is the problem. So I am posting the Logcat:

```
    03-13 17:09:33.388: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(1095): Registering sqlite logging func: /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases/AlarmSystem
    03-13 17:09:33.408: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(1095): DB info: open db, path = /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases , key = 9lYvmWqw, flag = 6, cannot stat file, errno = 2, message = No such file or directory
    03-13 17:09:33.408: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(1095): DB info: path = /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases , key = 9lYvmWqw, handle: 0x8ccc98, type: w, r/w: (0,1), mode: truncate, disk free size: 777 M
    03-13 17:09:33.588: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(1095): DB info: close db, path = /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases , key = 9lYvmWqw, handle = 0x8ccc98, type = w, r/w = (0, 0)
    03-13 17:09:33.588: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(1095): DB info: open db, path = /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases , key = 9lYvmWqw, flag = 6, file size = 4096
    03-13 17:09:33.588: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(1095): DB info: path = /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases , key = 9lYvmWqw, handle: 0x8f3100, type: w, r/w: (0,1), mode: truncate, disk free size: 777 M
    03-13 17:09:33.588: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(1095): DB info: close db, path = /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases , key = 9lYvmWqw, handle = 0x8f3100, type = w, r/w = (0, 0)
    03-13 17:09:33.598: D/AndroidRuntime(1095): Shutting down VM
    03-13 17:09:33.598: W/dalvikvm(1095): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ae0228)
    03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.devicecontrolpanel/com.example.devicecontrolpanel.Main}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases/AlarmSystem (conn# 0) already closed
    03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2205)
    03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2240)
    03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
    03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1262)
    03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
    03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
    03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases/AlarmSystem (conn# 0) already closed
    03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyDbIsOpen(SQLiteDatabase.java:2194)
    03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.lock(SQLiteDatabase.java:448)
    03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.lock(SQLiteDatabase.java:435)
    03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:79)
    03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:176)
    03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:168)
    03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at com.example.devicecontrolpanel.DataBaseAdapter.getAlarmsCount(DataBaseAdapter.java:190)
    03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at com.example.devicecontrolpanel.DataBaseAdapter.getAllAlarmList(DataBaseAdapter.java:117)
    03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at com.example.devicecontrolpanel.Main.onCreate(Main.java:19)
    03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4538)
    03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
    03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
    03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     ... 11 more
    03-13 17:16:48.144: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(2080): Registering sqlite logging func: /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases/AlarmSystem
    03-13 17:16:48.144: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(2080): DB info: open db, path = /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases , key = 9lYvmWqw, flag = 6, cannot stat file, errno = 2, message = No such file or directory
    03-13 17:16:48.164: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(2080): DB info: path = /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases , key = 9lYvmWqw, handle: 0x86b220, type: w, r/w: (0,1), mode: truncate, disk free size: 777 M
    03-13 17:16:48.384: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(2080): DB info: close db, path = /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases , key = 9lYvmWqw, handle = 0x86b220, type = w, r/w = (0, 0)
    03-13 17:16:48.384: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(2080): DB info: open db, path = /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases , key = 9lYvmWqw, flag = 6, file size = 5120
    03-13 17:16:48.384: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(2080): DB info: path = /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases , key = 9lYvmWqw, handle: 0x897800, type: w, r/w: (0,1), mode: truncate, disk free size: 777 M
    03-13 17:16:48.384: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(2080): DB info: close db, path = /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases , key = 9lYvmWqw, handle = 0x897800, type = w, r/w = (0, 0)
    03-13 17:16:48.394: D/AndroidRuntime(2080): Shutting down VM
    03-13 17:16:48.414: W/dalvikvm(2080): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ae0228)
    03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.devicecontrolpanel/com.example.devicecontrolpanel.Main}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases/AlarmSystem (conn# 0) already closed
    03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2205)
    03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2240)
    03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
    03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1262)
    03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
    03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
    03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases/AlarmSystem (conn# 0) already closed
    03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyDbIsOpen(SQLiteDatabase.java:2194)
    03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.lock(SQLiteDatabase.java:448)
    03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.lock(SQLiteDatabase.java:435)
    03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:79)
    03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:176)
    03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:168)
    03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at com.example.devicecontrolpanel.DataBaseAdapter.getAlarmsCount(DataBaseAdapter.java:196)
    03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at com.example.devicecontrolpanel.DataBaseAdapter.getAllAlarmList(DataBaseAdapter.java:123)
    03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at com.example.devicecontrolpanel.Main.onCreate(Main.java:19)
    03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4538)
    03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
    03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
    03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Activity..?? can U please help me out.

Comment: Post the calling activity please. Your db has no open connection, thats what the execption tells you.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385059/sqlite-exception-database-already-closed?noredirect=1#comment21744528_15385059) is the calling activity in this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general it is better to separate the wrapper method ( in your case `addAlarm, editAlarm, deleteAlarm` ) in a seperate class. I suggest you to create a new class with name `myAppDataSource` and add all the wrapper method in that class to make your life easier.

The code for that class will look like this:

```
 public class StudyManagerDataSource {

    SQLiteOpenHelper dbHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase database;

public StudyManagerDataSource(Context context) {
            dbHelper = new DatabaseAdapter(context);

        }

public void addAlarm(Alarm alarm)
{  

    // open the database connection 
    open();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_DESC, alarm.getDesc());
    values.put(KEY_REPEAT_DAY, alarm.getRepeatDay());
    values.put(KEY_REPEAT_TYPE, alarm.getRepeatType());
    values.put(KEY_CALENDAR, Long.toString(alarm.getCalendarInMillis()));
    values.put(KEY_APP, alarm.getApp());
    values.put(KEY_ACTIVE, alarm.getActive());
    database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    // I will suggest to keep the connection to the database open when your app is 
    // running, the recommended time to close the connection is when your app is 
    //going to pause/stop.
    close();
}

public void open() {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Database Opened");
    } // end method open

public void close() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Database Closed");
        dbHelper.close();
    } // end method close
}
```

Comment: ContentProviders can make the life much more easier when dealing with SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

You should open connection to the database first, try put db.open() in the onCreateMethod()

```
//creating table
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    db.open();
    String CREATE_TABLE = "Create Table "+TABLE_NAME+"("
            +KEY_ALARM_ID+" integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT, "+KEY_DESC+" TEXT, "+KEY_REPEAT_DAY+ " TEXT,"
            +KEY_REPEAT_TYPE+" integer, "+KEY_CALENDAR+" TEXT, "+KEY_APP+" TEXT, "+KEY_ACTIVE+" integer );";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}
```

Comment: `db.open` is not a defined method.

Comment: Try to separate your functions into different class. SQLite Open Helper class should only contain onCreate() and onUpdate() method. So you should write another class, for example Alarm class. Then you can create connection to database and add addAlarm() method in this class.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void addAlarm(Alarm alarm)
{  

    // open the database connection 
   database=this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_DESC, alarm.getDesc());
    values.put(KEY_REPEAT_DAY, alarm.getRepeatDay());
    values.put(KEY_REPEAT_TYPE, alarm.getRepeatType());
    values.put(KEY_CALENDAR, Long.toString(alarm.getCalendarInMillis()));
    values.put(KEY_APP, alarm.getApp());
    values.put(KEY_ACTIVE, alarm.getActive());
    database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    // I will suggest to keep the connection to the database open when your app is 
    // running, the recommended time to close the connection is when your app is 
    //going to pause/stop.
    database.close();
}
```