# SQLite Exception, Database Already Closed

Tags: java, android

I am writing the following code, this code is for creating a class which calls a class `DataBaseAdapter`. the `DataBaseAdapter` Class is responsible for all database connectivity and methods are there for storing values in database.:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    DataBaseAdapter db = new DataBaseAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    Alarm al = new Alarm(1,"qwer",new int[] {1,1,1,0,1,0,1}, 1, 382562495,"App", 1);
    db.addAlarm(al);
    ScrollView sc= (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollBody);
    TableLayout tb = db.getAllAlarmList(getApplicationContext());
    sc.addView(tb);
    }
}
```

This is my logcat:

```
03-13 17:09:33.388: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(1095): Registering sqlite logging func: /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases/AlarmSystem
03-13 17:09:33.408: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(1095): DB info: open db, path = /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases , key = 9lYvmWqw, flag = 6, cannot stat file, errno = 2, message = No such file or directory
03-13 17:09:33.408: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(1095): DB info: path = /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases , key = 9lYvmWqw, handle: 0x8ccc98, type: w, r/w: (0,1), mode: truncate, disk free size: 777 M
03-13 17:09:33.588: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(1095): DB info: close db, path = /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases , key = 9lYvmWqw, handle = 0x8ccc98, type = w, r/w = (0, 0)
03-13 17:09:33.588: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(1095): DB info: open db, path = /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases , key = 9lYvmWqw, flag = 6, file size = 4096
03-13 17:09:33.588: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(1095): DB info: path = /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases , key = 9lYvmWqw, handle: 0x8f3100, type: w, r/w: (0,1), mode: truncate, disk free size: 777 M
03-13 17:09:33.588: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(1095): DB info: close db, path = /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases , key = 9lYvmWqw, handle = 0x8f3100, type = w, r/w = (0, 0)
03-13 17:09:33.598: D/AndroidRuntime(1095): Shutting down VM
03-13 17:09:33.598: W/dalvikvm(1095): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ae0228)
03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.devicecontrolpanel/com.example.devicecontrolpanel.Main}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases/AlarmSystem (conn# 0) already closed
03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2205)
03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2240)
03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1262)
03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases/AlarmSystem (conn# 0) already closed
03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyDbIsOpen(SQLiteDatabase.java:2194)
03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.lock(SQLiteDatabase.java:448)
03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.lock(SQLiteDatabase.java:435)
03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:79)
03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:176)
03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:168)
03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at com.example.devicecontrolpanel.DataBaseAdapter.getAlarmsCount(DataBaseAdapter.java:190)
03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at com.example.devicecontrolpanel.DataBaseAdapter.getAllAlarmList(DataBaseAdapter.java:117)
03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at com.example.devicecontrolpanel.Main.onCreate(Main.java:19)
03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4538)
03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
03-13 17:09:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     ... 11 more
03-13 17:16:48.144: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(2080): Registering sqlite logging func: /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases/AlarmSystem
03-13 17:16:48.144: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(2080): DB info: open db, path = /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases , key = 9lYvmWqw, flag = 6, cannot stat file, errno = 2, message = No such file or directory
03-13 17:16:48.164: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(2080): DB info: path = /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases , key = 9lYvmWqw, handle: 0x86b220, type: w, r/w: (0,1), mode: truncate, disk free size: 777 M
03-13 17:16:48.384: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(2080): DB info: close db, path = /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases , key = 9lYvmWqw, handle = 0x86b220, type = w, r/w = (0, 0)
03-13 17:16:48.384: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(2080): DB info: open db, path = /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases , key = 9lYvmWqw, flag = 6, file size = 5120
03-13 17:16:48.384: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(2080): DB info: path = /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases , key = 9lYvmWqw, handle: 0x897800, type: w, r/w: (0,1), mode: truncate, disk free size: 777 M
03-13 17:16:48.384: D/SqliteDatabaseCpp(2080): DB info: close db, path = /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases , key = 9lYvmWqw, handle = 0x897800, type = w, r/w = (0, 0)
03-13 17:16:48.394: D/AndroidRuntime(2080): Shutting down VM
03-13 17:16:48.414: W/dalvikvm(2080): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ae0228)
03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.devicecontrolpanel/com.example.devicecontrolpanel.Main}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases/AlarmSystem (conn# 0) already closed
03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2205)
03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2240)
03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1262)
03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/com.example.devicecontrolpanel/databases/AlarmSystem (conn# 0) already closed
03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyDbIsOpen(SQLiteDatabase.java:2194)
03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.lock(SQLiteDatabase.java:448)
03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.lock(SQLiteDatabase.java:435)
03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:79)
03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:176)
03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:168)
03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at com.example.devicecontrolpanel.DataBaseAdapter.getAlarmsCount(DataBaseAdapter.java:196)
03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at com.example.devicecontrolpanel.DataBaseAdapter.getAllAlarmList(DataBaseAdapter.java:123)
03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at com.example.devicecontrolpanel.Main.onCreate(Main.java:19)
03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4538)
03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
03-13 17:16:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2080):     ... 11 more
```

I am getting the error, SQL Exception, database already closed. but I am not getting why and how.?
What to do. Please Help.

Here is the code for getAllAlarmList:

```
public Alarm getAlarm(int id)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] colum = {KEY_ALARM_ID, KEY_DESC, KEY_REPEAT_DAY, KEY_REPEAT_TYPE, KEY_CALENDAR, KEY_APP, KEY_ACTIVE};

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, colum, KEY_ALARM_ID +"=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    else
        return null;

    int alarm_id=Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
    String desc = cursor.getString(1);
    String dayRepeat = cursor.getString(2);
    int[] repeatDay = new int[7];
    for(int m=0;m<7;m++)
    {
        repeatDay[m]=Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(dayRepeat.charAt(m)));
    }
    int repeatType = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3));
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(4)));
    String app = cursor.getString(5);
    int active = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(6));
    //change dayRepeat String to int[]

    Alarm alarm = new Alarm(alarm_id, desc, repeatDay, repeatType, cal.getTimeInMillis(), app, active);
    db.close();
    return alarm;
}
public TableLayout getAllAlarmList(Context con)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    TableLayout body = new TableLayout(con);
    TableLayout.LayoutParams TbodyLayout = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    body.setLayoutParams(TbodyLayout);
    body.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    LayoutParams layout = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    if(getAlarmsCount()>0)
    {
        int maxCount = getAlarmsCount();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            TableRow[] tr = new TableRow[maxCount];
            CheckBox[] check = new CheckBox[maxCount];
            initializeCheckBoxId(maxCount);
            int checkboxid = 100;
            int alarm_id;
            for(int i=0;i<maxCount;i++)
            {
                tr[i] = new TableRow(con);
                check[i]= new CheckBox(con);
                alarm_id=Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
                Alarm alarm = getAlarm(alarm_id);
                check[i].setText(alarm.getTimeInString()+"\n"+alarm.getDesc()+"\n"+alarm.getRepeatTypeInString());
                check[i].setVisibility(1);
                check[i].setEnabled(false);
                if(alarm.getActive()==1)
                {
                    check[i].setEnabled(true);
                }
                setCheckBoxId(checkboxid+alarm.getAlarmId());
                check[i].setId(checkboxid+alarm.getAlarmId());
                check[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tr[i].addView(check[i]);
                tr[i].setLayoutParams(layout);
                if(i%2==0)
                {
                    tr[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                }
                else
                {
                    tr[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                }
                body.addView(tr[i]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            TextView TV = new TextView(con);
            TV.setText("No Alarms Set.");
            TV.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            TV.setVisibility(1);
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(con);
            tableRow.setLayoutParams(layout);
            body.addView(tableRow);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        TextView TV = new TextView(con);
        TV.setText("No Alarms Set.");
        TV.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        TV.setVisibility(1);
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(con);
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(layout);
        body.addView(tableRow);
    }
    db.close();
    return body;
}
```

Here is the code to add the alarm to the database:

```
public void addAlarm(Alarm alarm)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    //values.put(KEY_ALARM_ID, alarm.getAlarmId());
    values.put(KEY_DESC, alarm.getDesc());
    values.put(KEY_REPEAT_DAY, alarm.getRepeatDay());
    values.put(KEY_REPEAT_TYPE, alarm.getRepeatType());
    values.put(KEY_CALENDAR, Long.toString(alarm.getCalendarInMillis()));
    values.put(KEY_APP, alarm.getApp());
    values.put(KEY_ACTIVE, alarm.getActive());

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

here is the code for getting the alarm count:

```
public int getAlarmsCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    db.close();
    return cursor.getCount();
}
```

Comment: plz also add getAllAlarmList method code from db class

Comment: Please show how `DataBaseAdapter` is defined.

Comment: I have defined DataBaseAdapter Class [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384550/android-sqlite-contentvalues-not-inserting?noredirect=1#comment21744398_15384550)

Comment: @VeerShubhranshuShrivastav : ok where is addAlarm method ?

Comment: @VeerShubhranshuShrivastav : u have problem inside getAlarmsCount(); method . make sure u are not opening db inside getAlarmsCount(); method

Comment: I added the code.. please have a look to it.

Comment: @VeerShubhranshuShrivastav : change getAlarmsCount() as : `public int getAlarmsCount(SQLiteDatabase db) {String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);cursor.close();return cursor.getCount();}`

Comment: Sorry sir.. but still the same problem.. I cant help it. not getting.. I did what you asked.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26097/discussion-between--k-and-veer-shubhranshu-shrivastav)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call `close()` on the underlying `SQLiteDatabase`. You should call [`SQLiteOpenHelper.close()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#close%28%29) instead. Change all `db.close()` into `this.close()` or plain `close()`

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
...
this.close();
```

If you call `SQLiteDatabase.close()` instead of `SQLiteOpenHelper.close()`, the `SQLiteOpenHelper` cannot know this and returns the already closed `SQLiteDatabase` object.