# do not start services

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

i create an alarm service and call it in main activity, but get this error that: "`unable to start service`".............
i create table in db.java and set variable by InsertMagnt in alarmservice.

```
DB DataBase = new DB();
DataBase.InsertMagnt(Acce_x, Acce_y, Acce_z, "", "", 1);
    DataBase.InsertMagnt(Meg_x, Meg_y, Meg_z, datetime, "", 2);
    DataBase.InsertMagnt(Tilt_x, Tilt_y, Tilt_z, datetime, Direct, 3);
    DataBase.InsertMagnt(lon, lat, 0, datetime, "", 4);
```

and main activity is:

```
Intent AlarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmService.class);
    pending = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, AlarmIntent, 0);
    alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 10 * 1000, pending);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Service Start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

i get this errors:

```
08-08 13:24:21.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9000): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.farzaneh.AlarmService@417c9cd8 with Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.example.farzaneh/.AlarmService (has extras) }: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "')" (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Acce_Log (X,Y,Z,Date) VALUES (0.0,0.0,0.0')
```

Comment: https://github.com/SheldonNeilson/Android-Alarm-Clock

Answer (score 0):

What's going on with this `insert` statement

```
INSERT INTO Acce_Log (X,Y,Z,Date) VALUES (0.0,0.0,0.0')//date is not inserted and the '
```

You have specified that `four values will be inserted but inserting only three,`and that `'`.Remove it,and pass the date as the last argument

Comment: you are saving date as text,are you aware of the datatype date in sql?\

Comment: @DividebyZero SQLite does not provide any data type for storing date

Answer (score 0):

Salam!

Your error is because of your mistakes about inserting a row into SQLite table (Look at your given error again!)

```
INSERT INTO Acce_Log (X, Y, Z, Date) VALUES (0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ')
                                    unrecognized token ----^
```

Please rectify your insert statement. Also note that SQLite does not provide any data type for storing date, you should store a date in either string or long format.

I recommend you to use long! use a `Calendar` object to convert your date into milliseconds since the epoch (in UTC timezone) and now its ready to be stored in  SQLite

**UPDATE #1**

Suppose I have the following table in the SQLite database

```
column name      type
-------------------------
   GID          INTEGER
  Name           TEXT
  Quan          INTEGER
 Surname         TEXT
```

Now, I want to populate this table with some sample data, For this purpose I'll use the following function.

```
public void addRow() {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("GID", 123);
    contentValues.put("Name", "Edward");
    contentValues.put("Quan", 12);
    contentValues.put("Surname", "Kenway");

    mDataBase.insert("Your table name", null, contentValues);
}
```

Comment: salam, i created date in acce_log by text:'database.execSQL("CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Acce_Log (" +
                "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL ," +
                "X DOUBLE, Y DOUBLE, Z DOUBLE,Date TEXT)");' and insert variable by database.execSQL("INSERT INTO Acce_Log (X,Y,Z,Date) VALUES" +
                        " (" + X + "," + Y + "," + Z + ",'" + date + "')");

Comment: @farzanehabolqasemi Please tell me what's type of `date` object ?

Comment: @farzanehabolqasemi Why didn't you use `ContentValues` ? Its very straightforward also its much better that concatenating string together. If you okay with it tell me to add some sample codes to my answer

Comment: should i write contentvalues instead TEXT? i do not know about this!!

Comment: @farzanehabolqasemi don't worry,keep calm !!! please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384550/android-sqlite-contentvalues-not-inserting or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971434/how-to-insert-value-in-data-base-using-sqlite-in-android

Comment: @farzanehabolqasemi If you found that links messed-up tell me to put some simple examples

Comment: i dont understand :(, i writed according to this sample but get error again, can you get me any example? thanks for your responses

Comment: @farzanehabolqasemi Hold on, I'll added some examples